# How to avoid forgetting making attributes private in class

Tags: java, eclipse, attributes, private, code-completion

I ALWAYS want to avoid that new attributes in a class are visible.
For java I can put private in front of the attributes. However because it's standard for me, I want to automate this set up via Eclipse code completion or error alert warnings.

How can I set up Eclipse so I can't forget anymore to make all the attributes of the classes private?

How can Eclipse assure that I never type following

```
package Test;

public class Test {
    String test;
}
```

How can Eclipse furthermore assure that I always type private as follows?

```
package Test;

public class Test {
    private String test;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way for Eclipse to enforce private fields. As package visible fields are perfectly valid, Eclipse should not prevent you from creating them.

I see two ways that can help you in this scenario, though.

1. You can check your code after you have created it. Use the [Unnecessary Code Detector plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/unnecessary-code-detector) to check your code for unnecessary code. This will add a warning to all fields that have a visibility that's greater than required by your code.
2. You can create a code snippet in Eclipse Code Recommenders Snipmatch (It comes bundled in some Eclipse packages. If  is not installed in your Eclipse already, get it from the [marketplace](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/snipmatch)). Open *Window > Show View > Other... > Code Recommenders > Snippets*. Then select *Add Snippet...*. Define yourself a snippet that creates a private field.

   In the *Metadata* tab, input a *name*, e.g. "private field" and a description, e.g. "Creates a private field". As *location*, select "Java type members". This ensures that this snippet is only available at places where you can create fields (i.e. not in method bodies). Leave the other fields blank.

   [image: Snippet editor metadata tab]

   Switch to the *Raw Source* tab, and input `private ${type} ${name};`. Save the snippet.

   Place the cursor at a place where you want to create the field, press *CTRL+ALT+SPACE* and type "private field". Press enter to select your snippet. This will now insert the *private* modifier and allows you to specify the type and name of the field by tabbing between those options.

   [image: Snipmatch completion]

   Once you've gotten used to this way of creating fields, it will make sure you never forget the modifier. You may even create additional snippets for other visibilities, should you need them.

   For more help, refer to Snipmatch's [manual](https://www.eclipse.org/recommenders/manual/#snippet-editing-sharing). **Disclaimer:** I am one of Snipmatch's developers.

Comment: Thank you! This answered my question.

Comment: Great. Care to mark my answer as accepted then? To do so, click on the grey check mark beneath the up/down vote arrows.